# Trigger nested `KeyboardInterrupt` try-except

Tags: python, exception, scikit-learn, mathematical-optimization, keyboardinterrupt

In areas like searching or optimization, some functions (e.g. `sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.fit`) are designed such that when `KeyboardInterrupt` is sent, it returns the current best result immediately (rather than raising an exception). This is convenient in the sense that a result is wanted.

But if I have a meta-optimization routine that uses this function as a sub-routine, my main routine will not have the chance of receiving `KeyboardInterrupt`, and it will continue running, which makes the program 
"unstoppable".

A example would be:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
def optimize_many_times_and_take_best(x, y, model=MLPRegressor()):
    best = -1
    try:
        for i in range(20):
            best = max(best, model.fit(x, y).score(x, y))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    return best
```

When I hit Ctrl-C, `model.fit` will return immediately, while `optimize_many_times_and_take_best` will continue its for loop because it did not receive any `KeyboardInterrupt`. It will call `model.fit` again within very short time, and I have to press Ctrl-C very fast many time before I can stop the program.

I'm wondering, for this kind of nested `KeyboardInterrupt` trap, is there any good solution to interrupt all optimization routines?

For this case, since `MLPRegressor` emits a `UserWarning` on `KeyboardInterrupt`, I can catch the warning instead, but is there any better solution? Do I have to write some message mechanism (like `warnings` or some `bool`) explicitly for all loops?